# boost::local_time Does not read correct iso_extended_format

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

I need to read time with ISO extended format, and convert it to UTC time, like Javascript's `Date` objects do:

> new Date("2014-12-19T15:53:14.533+01:00")
>
> 2014-12-19T14:53:14.533Z

In boost, there is no `boost::posix_time::from_iso_extended_string` and  `boost::posix_time::from_iso_string` does not parse time-zones. I try to use `boost::local_time::local_date_time` but it seems that it also do not work:

```
    std::stringstream ss("2014-12-19T15:53:14.533+01:00");
    boost::local_time::local_time_input_facet* 
            ifc= new boost::local_time::local_time_input_facet();
    ifc->set_iso_extended_format();
    ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), ifc));
    boost::local_time::local_date_time 
             zonetime(boost::local_time::not_a_date_time);
    if( ss >> zonetime ) {
        time = zonetime.utc_time();
    }
```

Any help or suggestions?

[Live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39eb557cd253d8ff)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time zone isn't parsed at all:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db615a6d17a7945f)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::posix_time::ptime time;
    try 
    {
        std::stringstream ss("2014-12-19T15:53:14.533+01:00");
        boost::local_time::local_time_input_facet* ifc= new boost::local_time::local_time_input_facet();
        ifc->set_iso_extended_format();
        ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), ifc));
        boost::local_time::local_date_time zonetime(boost::local_time::not_a_date_time);
        if( ss >> zonetime ) {
            time = zonetime.utc_time();
        }

        std::string remains;
        if (std::getline(ss, remains))
            std::cout << "Remaining: '" << remains << "'\n";

    }
    catch( std::exception const& e )
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR:" << e.what() <<std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "UTC time: " << time;

    return 0;  
}
```

Prints:

```
Remaining: '+01:00'
UTC time: 2014-Dec-19 15:53:14.533000
```

The ***[documentation says](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/date_time/local_time.html#local_date_time_operators)***:

> At this time, local_date_time objects can only be streamed in with a Posix Time Zone string. A complete description of a Posix Time Zone string can be found in the documentation for the posix_time_zone class.

So, you'll need to either parse timezones separately or use POSIX time zones. Yes, I reckon this is very confusing and a deficiency. In effect, you cannot use extended iso format with local times.

You migth be able to use the `%ZP` instead:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6aff4eaf942ff13)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::posix_time::ptime time;
    try 
    {
        std::stringstream ss("2014-12-19T15:53:14.533-07:00");

        boost::local_time::local_time_input_facet* ifc= new boost::local_time::local_time_input_facet("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%F %ZP");
        //ifc->set_iso_extended_format();
        ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), ifc));

        using namespace boost::local_time;
        local_date_time ldt(not_a_date_time);

        if(ss >> ldt) {
            time = ldt.utc_time();

            std::string remains;
            if (std::getline(ss, remains))
                std::cout << "Remaining: '" << remains << "'\n";
        }

    }
    catch( std::exception const& e )
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR:" << e.what() <<std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "UTC time: " << time;

    return 0;  
}
```

Prints

```
UTC time: 2014-Dec-19 22:53:14.533000
```

Comment: Thanks. it work. POSIX time zone are different that they have seconds, but i think nobody will ever use parts of a minutes. Please change time string to "2014-12-19T15:53:14.533-07:00", that's what I am asking.

Comment: @Arpegius TBH, the only reason I can see why this is simply not implemented: apparently everyone is content exchanging UTC datetimes in transit (and pass the timezone out of band if needed)

Comment: You might be right, but it is good to do more then just check for the "Z" character in string.